# Period and Quarter Sequence

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I'm trying to find a way to do a sequence for date periods and quarters(not sure if this is the correct term).

Basically this will help people to navigate dates based on weeks, periods, and quarters once I join this to our sales data. For example, if I just want to know the sales from last week, I could just use `WHERE WeekSequence = -1`... Another example is, a manager wants to get the sales data for the past quarter, I could just use `WHERE QuarterSequence = -1`... something like that.

[My current table:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ND0gX.png)

```
WeekStartDate  WeekEndDate  CurrentWeek  Period  Quarter  WeekSequence
----------------------------------------------------------------------
2020-08-03     2020-08-09   0            2       1        -5
2020-08-10     2020-08-16   0            2       1        -4
2020-08-17     2020-08-23   0            2       1        -3
2020-08-24     2020-08-30   0            2       1        -2
2020-08-31     2020-09-06   0            2       1        -1
2020-09-07     2020-09-13   1            3       1        0
2020-09-14     2020-09-20   0            3       1        1
2020-09-21     2020-09-27   0            3       1        2
2020-09-28     2020-10-04   0            3       1        3
2020-10-05     2020-10-11   0            4       2        4
2020-10-12     2020-10-18   0            4       2        5
```

What I want it to look like(highlighted):

[image: Goal]

Comment: Have a look at the following [blog](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5553/create-an-extended-date-dimension-for-a-sql-server-data-warehouse/)

Comment: Can you explain what "Period" is?

Comment: @Christian I'm referring to financial period and quarter. Apologies if that wasn't clear.

Comment: @PrebenHuybrechts this is more of creating the actual date dimension. this won't help tho...

Comment: @ChristianneRioOrtega OK but how is "Period" defined? That is, when (e.g. which month) does the financial period start and end?

Comment: @Christian, basically it was based from our financial week number. week 1-14 is period 1 and so on... also we start our financial week around july.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, just use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       (period -
        max(case when currentweek = 1 then period end) over ()
       ) as periodsequence,
       (quarter -
        max(case when currentweek = 1 then quarter end) over ()
       ) as quartersequence       
from t;
```

You can include this in a view rather than putting it in a table.